# List GCP Bucket Locations Via Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Google have provided the following documentation on what locations are presently available when creating storage buckets:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations

I essentially want to obtain that list via Python. Google Cloud allow you to retrieve the metadata for buckets already created, but I want to obtain the list of locations for deploying new buckets via Terraform. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no a direct way to get this information for a Storage Bucket as it is for a Compute Engine instance [for example](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regions/list.)

There is a [feature request open](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173197650) that you can follow to get updates on the implementation of this feature.

At the moment the only way to achieve this in a programatically way is to serve the data by yourself. For example I created this json file which you can serve from App Engine and request it from your application to access the data programatically in the meanwhile

```
{
    "North America": [{
        "Montreal": "NORTHAMERICA-NORTHEAST1",
        "Iowa": "US-CENTRAL1",
        "South Carolina": "US-EAST1",
        "Northern Virginia": "US-EAST4",
        "Oregon": "US-WEST1",
        "Los Angeles": "US-WEST2",
        "Salt Lake City": "US-WEST3",
        "Las Vegas": "US-WEST4"
    }],
    "South America": [{
        "Sao Paulo": "SOUTHAMERICA-EAST1"
    }],
    "Europe": [{
        "Finland": "EUROPE-NORTH1",
        "Belgium": "EUROPE-WEST1",
        "London": "EUROPE-WEST2",
        "Frankfurt": "EUROPE-WEST3",
        "Netherlands": "EUROPE-WEST4",
        "Zurich": "EUROPE-WEST6"
    }],
    "Asia": [{
        "Taiwan": "ASIA-EAST1",
        "Hong Kong": "ASIA-EAST2",
        "Tokyo": "ASIA-NORTHEAST1",
        "Osaka": "ASIA-NORTHEAST2",
        "Seoul": "ASIA-NORTHEAST3",
        "Mumbai": "ASIA-SOUTH1",
        "Singapore": "ASIA-SOUTHEAST1",
        "Jakarta": "ASIA-SOUTHEAST2"
    }],
    "Australia": [{
        "Sydney": "AUSTRALIA-SOUTHEAST1"
    }]
}
```